# replace rm with gio trash

Tags: bash, alias

I have created this **alias** to replace `rm` with `gio trash` ...

```
alias rm='function move2trash(){
    if hash gio &> /dev/null; then
        gio trash "$@" && \
        echo "File(s) moved to trash instead." && \
        echo "See \`man gio\` for more information."
    else
        echo "Removing file(s) is a bad habbit, instead you should move or rename them."
        echo "If you really have to remove some thing(s) you can use the full path i.e. \`/bin/rm\`."
    fi
}; move2trash'
```

But files get lost when running `sudo` in front of it ...

```
[~] touch test.file
[~] sudo rm test.file 
[~] sudo ls /root/.local/share/Trash/files/test.file
/root/.local/share/Trash/files/test.file
[~] touch test.file2
[~] sudo rm test.file2 
[~] sudo ls /root/.local/share/Trash/files/test.file2
ls: cannot access '/root/.local/share/Trash/files/test.file2': No such file or directory
[~, ERR:2]
```

Also I get errors when running **options** or **variables** with `rm` ...

```
[~] touch test.file3
[~] LC_ALL=C rm test.file3 
bash: Syntaxfehler beim unerwarteten Symbol »(«
[~, ERR:2] rm -i test.file3 
gio: Unbekannte Option -i

Aufruf:
  gio trash [OPTION …] [ORT…]

Dateien oder Ordner in den Papierkorb verschieben/wiederherstellen.

Optionen:
  -f, --force     Nicht vorhandene Dateien ignorieren und niemals nachfragen
  --empty         Den Papierkorb leeren
  --list          Dateien im Papierkorb mit ihren ursprünglichen Orten auflisten
  --restore       Eine Datei aus dem Papierkorb am ursprünglichen Ort wiederherstellen (erstellt unter Umständen wieder den Ordner)

Hinweis: Wenn der ursprüngliche Ort der gelöschten Datei bereits existiert, wird er mit der Option »--restore« nicht überschrieben, außer »--force« ist gesetzt.
```

Hope you guys have some advice to make this **alias** more reliable,
or at least explain to me why this **alias** doesn't work with `sudo` and **how to remove options**.

Comment: Why would you make an alias that first defines a function and then runs it, instead of _just making a function (instead of an alias) in the first place_?

Comment: Mind, aliases _never_ worked with sudo in the first place -- never have, never will. They're simple prefix substitution, and they're part of process-local state; when you invoke an `execve()` call to invoke a different executable (like sudo), the original shell's state is replaced with a clean image of the `sudo` executable.

Comment: ...one thing you _can_ do with functions (but not aliases) is export them through the environment; but whether that makes them survive sudo depends on the details of your `/etc/sudoers` file -- if sudo is configured to discard environment variables, exported functions won't make it through either. And you need to have a shell on the other side of the sudo to execute that function, even if it _is_ exported -- by default, sudo just directly invokes the requested executable with no shell in the way.

Comment: So what you'd typically end up with is needing something like `sudo_move2trash() { sudo bash -c "$(declare -f move2trash); "'move2trash "$@"' _ "$@"; }` (and then to use `sudo_move2trash` instead of `sudo move2trash`) _in addition to_ a bare function declaration of `move2trash`.

Comment: Also -- see https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete about the `function` keyword. `function funcname() {` combines the POSIX syntax `funcname() {` and the legacy ksh syntax `function funcname {` in a way that's incompatible with _both_ POSIX sh and legacy ksh.